# Joomla редирект на главную, если в строке запроса есть параметры

Tags: joomla, get, редирект

Если в адресной строке есть знак вопроса (например `example.com/?ads`) после адреса хоста, сразу же перебрасывает на главную. Если в строку до или вместо знака вопроса поставить какой-то путь (например `example.com/asd?ads`), то кидает 404, как и ожидается. Собственно вопрос: какие могут быть причины того, что в первом случае редиректит на главную и параметры запроса в строке сбрасываются. `.htaccess` проверял, и проверил так же все файлы, где есть `header('/"Location`

Comment: не используется ли какой-нибудь SEF-компонент в проекте?

Comment: и покажите всё-таки ваш .htaccess